# Forcing a java app to become the focused window

Tags: java, swing, window

Is it possible to write something that will auto make a java app the focused window every thirty or so seconds or does this need to be something done at the OS level?

Comment: That sounds like one of the most horrible things you could do to your users. The equivalent of a nagging child that needs its parents attention every few seconds. Are there any valid reasons why you'd want to do this?

Comment: I've written several apps that are the reason for the machine's existence - think monitoring some system. In these cases this is a valid technique.

Comment: But the only way the window should become hidden is because the user has hidden it (say because he has to actually fix a problem that was detected by the monitoring system ;) ) for some reason. I mean if it's the machines reason of existence someone will have to check the monitor regularly and would notice it anyways? Anyways I think the best you can hope for, is that you can place them above windows from the same VM. For something more global I doubt a java only solution would work.

Comment: @Voo, it's a single purpose machine, it's a VM that runs a java app that the users interact with, we have a debug window to capture console output and the users are closing it, causing the app to close without calling it's shutdown hook. The machines have no mouse or keyboard and should only be able to use the touchscreen app and that's it. The machines run a small linux distro that simply launches a remote desktop connection and whenever the machine goes into powersaver mode it causes a display error, minimizing the app which causes the workers to become confused and close the console window.

Comment: Send the debug output to a file, and use tail -f to monitor it... Disable power save :-) And pop the window to front whenever something important happens.

Comment: Also, I want the users to not be able to do anything on the machine, at all, nothing on the desktop, nothing.

Comment: If it's a special purpose machine, nothing stops you from starting X without a window manager, and then start the java program as the single program. (Can do that from a start up script - as long as the DISPLAY env variable is set - probably to ":0" (without the citation marks)

Comment: In windows xp? These are all connected to windows xp VMs because the last machine was a web based app that needed to also be able to call solidworks. Plus it's handy to be able to administer them the same as other machines on our network I imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29).

Comment: Component.requestFocus() as well

Comment: I would call this in a Swing Timer, but toFront() may not work for all OS's (please see the API for details).